# Brownie : Contract Functionality not available in local environment

Tags: brownie, test

I have set up a new brownie project (`brownie bake yearn strategy mix`). When I try running tests I get this error :

```
brownie.exceptions.BrownieEnvironmentError: Functionality not available in local environment
```

It seems brownie doesn't like the return of functions similar to this one :

`yield Contract(token_address)`

saying Contract Functionality is not available in local environment.

The token address is DAI token from mainnet, and I'm using mainnet-fork.

Comment: It's probably not available on a local environment. Have you tried swapping that out with something else?

Comment: I have followed your brownie tutorial a while ago and deleted Ganach-CLI mainnet fork and replaced by my own mainnet-fork to use Alchemy, that's why it didnt work. When i run Ganache-CLI Hardhat mainnet fork for example it works. Another question tho, I couldnt figure out how to retrieve the original Ganache-CLI Mainnet-Fork, even by uninstall/install brownie. Any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are specifying your network, the yearn-vaults repo defaults to `development` which is likely why this isn't working for you.

for instance, `brownie test --network mainnet-fork`

Answer (score 0):

I added ".from_explorer(address)" to MintableForkToken and Contract objects, this solved the issue. Please see below:

```
    dai = MintableForkToken.from_explorer(dai_addr) #See here
    dai._mint_for_testing(accounts[0], amount)

    registry = Contract.from_explorer(registry_addr) #See here
    pool_addr = registry.find_pool_for_coins(dai_addr, usdc_addr)
    pool = Contract.from_explorer(pool_addr)

    dai.approve(pool_addr, amount, {"from": accounts[0]})
    pool.add_liquidity([amount, 0, 0], 0, {"from": accounts[0]})

    gauges = registry.get_gauges(pool_addr)
    gauge_addr = gauges[0][0]
    gauge_contract = interface.LiquidityGauge(gauge_addr)

    lp_token = MintableForkToken.from_explorer(gauge_contract.lp_token())
    lp_token.approve(gauge_addr, amount, {"from": accounts[0]})
    gauge_contract.deposit(lp_token.balanceOf(accounts[0]), {"from": accounts[0]})
```

You need to add your Etherscan API key to your given network:

```
brownie networks modify mainnet-fork explorer=https://api.etherscan.io/api?apikey=_____________________
```